# How to stop findbugs-maven-plugin from validating querydsl generated class

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, findbugs, querydsl

How can I configure the findbugs-maven-plugin to skip validating the generated code for Querydsl?
or
How can I configure Querydsl to generate the QTransactions.java to another package?

When running mvn clean install I get the following problem:

```
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:check (default) @ transactions ---
[INFO] BugInstance size is 1
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] Total bugs: 1
[INFO] com.example.transactions.QTransaction doesn't override com.mysema.query.types.path.BeanPath.equals(Object) ["com.example.transactions.QTransaction"] At QTransaction.java:[lines 19-53]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Transactions.java:

```
package com.example.transactions;

//imports 

@Entity(name="Transaction")
@EntityListeners({TransactionStateListener.class})
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected Long txId;

    @Column(name="txType", nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected TransactionType type;

    @Column(name="state", nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected TransactionState state;       

    @Transient
    protected TransactionState oldState;

    @Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    protected Long accountId;

    @Column(length=32)  
    protected String productId;

    @Column(length=32)
    protected String externalProductId;

    @Column(length=64)
    protected String externalTxId;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(updatable=false)
    protected DateTime createdDateTime;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(insertable=false)
    protected DateTime lastModifiedDateTime;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(insertable=false)
    protected DateTime executedDateTime;    

    @Version
    protected Integer version;

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostLoad
    void updateOldState() {
        oldState = state;
    }

    @PrePersist
    void prePersist() throws InvalidTxStateException {
        state = TransactionState.INITIALIZED;
        createdDateTime = DateTime.now();       
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void preUpdate() {      
        lastModifiedDateTime = DateTime.now();
        if (state == TransactionState.EXECUTED) {
            executedDateTime = DateTime.now(); 
        }
    }

    //Getters and setters
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...

    <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <onlyAnalyze>com.example.-</onlyAnalyze>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<!--                            Specifies the directory in which the query types are generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources-jpa</outputDirectory>
<!--                            States that the APT code generator should look for JPA annotations -->
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution after looking around, a lot thanks to Timos partial solution.

Basically it's 2 parts.

1. Generate the QueryDSL classes to another package
2. Exclude that package from findbugs-maven-plugin (See http://blog.sinarf.org/2009/03/exclude-generated-classes-from-findbugs.html)

pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources-jpa</outputDirectory>
                   <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                   <options>
                       <querydsl.packageSuffix>.generated</querydsl.packageSuffix>
                   </options>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

findbugs-exclude.xml:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Package name="com.example.transactions.generated" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: where should I put the findbugs-exclude.xml file? I tried placing it in the same folder as parent pom. But that didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Chanakaudaya I placed indbugs-exclude.xml file  in the same folder as parent pom and it worked. So, it must be some problems in your configurations.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question I don't have an answer.

You can generate the Q-classes to subpackage via the `querydsl.packageSuffix` APT option like documented here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.3/reference/html/ch03s03.html#d0e1847

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to find the answer solution to the question.